# can you help me solve this? Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem with this

#### Error:

> (Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in)

after installing plugins from a theme. I am still studying `PHP`. Can some please help fix this code referred to the error.

here is the code:

```
if ( $this->result && ! is_wp_error( $this->result ) ) {
    if ( ! $this->error ) {
        echo '<div class="updated js-update-details" data-update-details="progress-' . esc_attr( $this->upgrader->update_current ) . '">' .
             '<p>' . sprintf( $this->upgrader->strings['skin_update_successful'], $title ) .
             ' <button type="button" class="hide-if-no-js button-link js-update-details-toggle" aria-expanded="false">' . __( 'Show details.' ) . '</button>' .
             '</p></div>';
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(\'.waiting-' . esc_js($this->upgrader->update_current) . '\').hide();</script>';
}
```

Comment: what is the value of  `$this->upgrader->strings['skin_update_successful']`?

Answer (score 0):

This warning message means that `$this->upgrader->strings['skin_update_successful']` have more placeholders (like `%s`) than you pass variables into `sprintf` (you pass only `$title`). Just check what a string you have in `$this->upgrader->strings['skin_update_successful']` (you can just printout it).

For example this code will throw the same warning message:

```
<?php
sprintf('foo %s %s', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

```
$data = call_web_service(); // return array()
foreach ($data as $d)
echo sprintf("<div>our %65 discount is : %s </div>",
$d["discount"]
);
```

use %65 in my string

sprintf seek every % and if counts of them is not equal to your parameters return this error